# Jquery Tooltip 'content' and break line not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to break the line in my tooltip text. For some reason the `content` function for Jquery doesn't work on my side.

Here's my code :

HTML :

```
                <div class="defect-info flex-fill">
                    <div class="defect-title"></div>
                    <div class="defect-assigned-contractor">Contractor:
                        <span class="contractor-name"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Javascript :

```
                var newDefectEl = $('#templates .defect-card').clone();
                var contractorNameEl = newDefectEl.find('.defect-assigned-contractor .contractor-name');
                contractorNameEl.attr('id', defect.assigned_contractor_user_id);
                // contractorNameEl.attr('title', "Test to <br/> break line <br/> here."); 
                contractorNameEl.text(defect.assigned_contractor.name);

                contractorNameEl.tooltip({
                    placement: 'bottom',
                    title: "Test to <br/> break line <br/> here.",
                    items: "span",
                    content: function() {
                        return $(this).attr('title');
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Can you add you HTML as well.

Comment: What is `newDefectEl`

Comment: edited, its the parent for the contractorNameEl, right now the tooltip is targeting the right place, the tooltip title is showing its just that the text not able to break into new line because the `content` function now running

Comment: @M.Izzat Do you use the tooltip plugin of jQuery UI? Because there are no `title` and `placement` options in this plugin, as you can see here https://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/